# Trying to find a very short story, about a man who goes to hell

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Possibly from around 60s/70s. A man goes to Hell. He realises that as he won’t die in Hell, he only needed to get used to the burning and pain and then he'll be able  to cope.

The final bit was about how it turned freezing cold. The story was only a couple of pages long, so probably in an anthology or similar.

Comment: This sounds a lot like [a novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Niven_and_Pournelle_novel))  by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle's. Are you sure it was a short story?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! No it’s not that one - it’s just one character and very short.

Comment: I remember reading this - IIRC after he becomes adjusted to the burning he starts getting friendly with a woman in the same predicament...then it goes cold. Sorry no idea what the title is

Comment: I remember the story too, but a cursory google search doesn't do anything. Something tells me that it's by Asimov (or possibly Clarke), but I am notoriously bad at remembering authors.